# Windows Server 2008 R2 fails to boot in UEFI Mode

Tags: windows-server-2008, uefi, usb-boot

I have created a bootable USB for Windows Sever 2008 R2. By default UEFI is not able to find all the required files to boot from the media. After following [this post](http://www.jaxidian.org/update/2011/01/28/199/) the booting is enabled. Even though the booting starts, it gets stuck on the "Starting Windows" screen after few seconds. It does not progress further even after long waiting. Seems it has stopped doing anything.

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: There are known issues trying to boot from usb on uefi. http://www.jaxidian.org/update/2011/01/28/199/

Comment: I am copying all installation files from a installation DVD. But that time boot files are not detected by UEFI loader. The link describes how we can make it detectable by UEFI loader.